# PowerShell ConvertTo-Json does not convert Array as expected

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I am trying to manipulate JSON object that has an array nested. The following PowerShell commands:

```
@{testArray=@(1,2)} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
@{testArray=@(@{prop1=1})} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
@{testArray=@(@{prop1=@(1,2)})} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Produce the following output:

```
{"testArray":[1,2]}
{"testArray":[{"prop1":1}]}
{"testArray":[{"prop1":"1 2"}]}
```

The first two do what I would expect but the last one doesn't. I would expect output:

```
{"testArray":[{"prop1":[1,2]}]}
```

What am I missing here? Using PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to specify the depth for ConvertTo-Json

```
 @{testArray=@(@{prop1=@(1,2)})} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 -Compress
```

Will return

```
{"testArray":[{"prop1":[1,2]}]}
```